# I get error when I try sudo apt-get update command on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

This is the following error:

```
     W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

     W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

     E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: All this means is that the file was not found on the server... Punch it in to your browser and you will see that it was not found. Try and clear out your apt-get cache. `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: I tried that but it gave me same error after trying update again.

Comment: I am trying to download Java from here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 0):

Try doing update.Assuming you are trying to install java

Try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Well I can't do update. that'S the problem.

Comment: can you post the complete sequence of commands

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
worked fine.

Comment: but 
sudo apt-get update
gave me the error up in the question.

Comment: open this in your browser http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/ you can see quantal(12.10 is not listed) perhaps you will have to use some other repository, otherwise browse inside the existing release folders, download .deb file and then install it

Comment: Is there any link for instructions for 12.10? I don't know Ubuntu very much.

Comment: It also gives those errors in the  middle : Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                    
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages             
  404  Not Found

Comment: try this http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/pool/main/o/oracle-java7-installer/oracle-jdk7-installer_7u10-0~webupd8~0_all.deb open in browser download this and install by double clicking ,